# Set Div Height to Another Div Height

Tags: javascript, dom, html, height

I know similar questions have been asked and I have referenced them, but have yet to get this to work. I have an aside that may not have as much content as the main section next to it. I am using the load event window.load to run my script called asideHeightSet below is the snippet that calls it:

```
  <script>
    window.onload=function(){

        asideHeightSet("main_content_aside", "main_content_section");
    }
  </script>
```

I have other functions that are executing fine from there and this snippet is after I can any dependent jQuery libraries. My javascript for the asideHeightSet is:

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
function asideHeightSet(aside, section){
var sectionHeight = $(section).style.height;
$(aside).style.height= sectionHeight;

}
```

I ran the firebug debugger in firefox and it keeps on showing that the height of the section is blank it outputs "" in the watch when I step through.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

---

This did it for me:

function asideHeightSet(aside, section){
var sectionHeight = $(section).offsetHeight-22;

$(aside).style.height = sectionHeight+"px";

}

the 22 was to take into account for padding and border of aside.

Comment: Updated the answer after a short test. Try it.

Comment: It worked thanks. I posted the full code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the code you provided lets me get the height of the elements with

```
$(section).offsetHeight
```

style height returns none because probably there are no height css style associated with the element. Try it and tell me what the results are.

Comment: Exactly the reverse there:  `onload` fires after all the content has loaded, including images that can affect a `div` size.  `document.ready` just means the DOM is loaded and available to be  manipulated, but the other resources aren't ready.

Comment: I said it has quirks in it's implementation, aka it's not reliable, not that the page is not loaded.

Comment: It is the same issue in all 3 major ones chrome, ie, ff.